# Opening Full node

Tags: full-node

When I try to open my node this is the error that pops up

"Error: Cannot parse configuration file: parse error on line 1: curl https://bitnodes.io/install-full-node.sh | sh."

Does anyone know how to fix this so I can get my node up and running again?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `curl https://bitnodes.io/install-full-node.sh | sh.` from your bitcoin.conf file

Comment: I can't find my bitcoin.conf file. The closest thing I was able to locate was a qt.conf file

Comment: Wherever you put this line, remove it. It is a terminal command, not an option to bitcoin nor a command for bitcoin. How are you starting Bitcoin Core?